# Get doc value within cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

My Cloud Firestore database looks like this:

```
users
 |          
 |----id----(name,age)
 |----id----(name,age)
 |----id----(name,age)
 |----id----(name,age)
 |----id----(name,age)
...
```

I'm writing a query through all the elements:

```
db.collection('users').get()
.then(
    (results) => {          
        results.forEach((doc) => {
            //how to get the id that represents this doc?
        });
        response.json();
    }           
)
.catch(function (error) {
    console.error("Error getting user: ", error);
    response.send(error)
});
```

My question is simple: the variable **doc** represents an id (that contains a collection with name and age). How can I get this id? can I retrieve it from **doc** somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually quite simple. The `doc` variable is actually [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.19.x/DocumentSnapshot), and you get its ID from its `id` property. So:

```
db.collection('users').get()
.then(
    (results) => {          
        results.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(doc.id);
        });
    }           
)
.catch(function (error) {
    console.error("Error getting user: ", error);
    response.send(error)
});
```